# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,open

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm new here and I apologize if i break the law of the site or something, and please alert me about that.

I am currently working on a project and desperately need help.In summary, I downloaded the source code for the "Bob-emploi" platform from GitHub [here source code](https://github.com/bayesimpact/bob-emploi). According to Read-Me,I should download the Docker app and apply this command "docker-compose up -d frontend-dev" to Windows PowerShell,But I get these problems :

```
Running node tests…


(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:161) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
  download.js
    ✓ should run properly (359ms)
    ✓ should restrict the download to specific table if specified in argument

  aux-pages-redirect lambda function
    ✓ should not touch the landing page
    ✓ redirects "/conseiller/ressources" to the client endpoint "bootstrap"
    ✓ redirects "/eval/" to the client endpoint "eval"
    ✓ redirects "/mini" to the client endpoint "mini-onboarding"
    ✓ redirects "/retours" to the client endpoint "nps"
    ✓ redirects "/statut/" to the client endpoint "statusUpdate"
    ✓ redirects "/unsubscribe" to the client endpoint "unsubscribe"
    ✓ redirects "/conseiller/ressources" to "/bootstrap.html" and the client knows about it
    ✓ redirects "/eval" to "/eval.html" and the client knows about it
    ✓ redirects "/mini" to "/mini-onboarding.html" and the client knows about it
    ✓ redirects "/retours" to "/nps.html" and the client knows about it
    ✓ redirects "/statut" to "/statut.html" and the client knows about it
    ✓ redirects "/unsubscribe" to "/unsubscribe.html" and the client knows about it
    ✓ redirects "/conseiller/nouveau-profil-et-projet" to "/bootstrap.html" and nginx knows about it
(node:161) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
    ✓ redirects "/eval" to "/eval.html" and nginx knows about it
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
    ✓ redirects "/mini" to "/mini-onboarding.html" and nginx knows about it
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
    ✓ redirects "/retours" to "/nps.html" and nginx knows about it
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)
    ✓ redirects "/statut" to "/statut.html" and nginx knows about it
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'
    ✓ redirects "/unsubscribe" to "/unsubscribe.html" and nginx knows about it
(node:161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 7)


  21 passing (430ms)

Checking Typescript types…
src/components/france_departements.tsx(1700,13): error TS2322: Type '{ children: (Element | Element[])[]; max?: string | number | undefined; required?: boolean | undefined; low?: number | undefined; high?: number | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; ... 355 more ...; viewBox: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>'.
  Types of property 'crossOrigin' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"" | "anonymous" | "use-credentials" | undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"" | "anonymous" | "use-credentials" | undefined'.
src/components/pages/eval.tsx(766,9): error TS2774: This condition will always return true since the function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?
src/components/suggestions.tsx(145,9): error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
ERROR: Service 'frontend-dev' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c test -n "$SKIP_TEST" && echo "Skipping tests" || ./entrypoint.sh ./lint_and_test.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV3gs.png)

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVtYL.png)

so, please how i can fix these problems.

Comment: Hi @ziad and welcome to SO. Can you please edit your question above and include the error output in code blocks ? Screenshots are note suitable for that: no one can copy paste from them (if needed for a research for example), they cannot be indexed by search engines, and they are in most cases far less readable than basic text. Moreover, you included them as external links which splits the information on several pages. Thanks.

Comment: yes, of course i can edit it, thank you for your notice.

Comment: `no such file or directory, open '/usr/app/release/nginx.conf'`. Did you check that this file exists in your container ?

Comment: yes, but exists in another path "/frontend/release/nginx.conf". this path '/usr/app/' doesn't exists i didn't find it.

Comment: Well then either change where the file is being looked at or move the file to the correct location.

Comment: that's exactly my problem i don't know how i can do this change or move a file to right location

Comment: please, nobody has any solution

Comment: The project simply does not build (just tried). Either you know how to fix and you provide a pull request to the authors, or you file an issue on their github project. There is also a mail on their readme page.

Comment: okay ,thank you i will try in github.